# OpenGL context inside Emacs buffer

Tags: opengl, emacs

I'm looking for a way to render an opengl scene inside an emacs buffer. Is there a best-practice way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code:

```
  (assoc 'window-id (frame-parameters (selected-frame)))
```

will, get you the window id for X11.  I'm not sure about other platforms.  Once you have that, you can do things to the window from any other X application you want.

If you want to use all Emacs Lisp code, you will need to use the xlib interface, which was adopted into xwem which is a Window manager written in Emacs Lisp.

http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/xwem